# Issue with connecting with API on WRDS batch jobs

Tags: sas, wrds, wrds-compusat

I am trying to run a sas file as a batch job on the WRDS cloud. This includes pulling a large amount of data from an API. When running the SAS file in the WRDS online SAS studio the file works as expected. When using the batch job it creates the same three errors for each HTTP API request.

```
ERROR: Unable to establish connection to api.usa.gov.
ERROR: Unable to establish connection to api.usa.gov.
ERROR: Unable to connect to Web server.
```

the request is a simple HTTP GET:

```
proc http
    method = "get" url ="API url" out = rept;
run;
```

Any help enabling the file to work on the WRDS cloud would be helpful.

Comment: Are you running the batch job on a different server or on your own machine? If it's on a different server, you may need to add the URL to an allowlist, go through a proxy, etc.

Comment: Try adding `headerout=` to capture potentially useful messages that you can add to your question.  There also might be proxy server settings made for you when you connect through your selected EG profile.  You can LOG all the active options in your Profile by submitting `Proc OPTIONS; run;`  Do the same with your batch run and compare the settings.